# How to enable a service account to deploy ssl cert to a google app engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-iam

I want to automate the deployment of ssl certs to my Google App Engine project. I want to be able to use a service account to do this.

This is my commands:

```
PROJECT=mycompany
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /Users/antkong/gcloud_keys/${PROJECT}.json
gcloud app --project=${PROJECT} ssl-certificates create --display-name='certbot-$CERT_NAME' \
        --certificate=./letsencrypt-config/live/${DOMAIN}/cert.pem \
        --private-key=./letsencrypt-config/live/${DOMAIN}/privkey.pem
```

However I got this error:

```
Activated service account credentials for: [mycompany@appspot.gserviceaccount.com]
ERROR: (gcloud.app.ssl-certificates.create) User [mycompany@appspot.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access app [mycompany] (or it may not exist): Caller is not authorized to administer this certificate. You must be a verified owner of the certificate's domain(s) [zeetings-dev.com] to create, modify, or delete this resource. Your authorized domain(s) are []. If you own the certificate domain(s), you can obtain authorization by verifying ownership via the Webmaster Central portal: https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification.
```

What kind of permissions I can grant to the service a/c to make it work?

I have granted these roles to the service account:

[image]

Comment: Have you validated the domain [zeetings-dev.com] for which you are creating the certificate? You can do it using the Console, navigate to APIs & Services -> Credentials, and then click on Domain Verification. Then Add a domain.

Comment: Already verified. Your comment does not even remotely address the issue outlined in the question - how to automate the upload of ssl cert.

Comment: @AnthonyKong - Did you solve this problem? If yes, what was the solution?

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry, I haven't found a solution yet

Comment: First, you need to verify your domain before you can do anything with it. Follow this document: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application

Comment: See prior comments. Domains have been verified ages ago. I just want to automate the process.

Comment: Based upon the error message, the domain is not verified or it is verified for a different Project. Run this command to confirm `gcloud domains list-user-verified`. Then review `gcloud domains verify`

Comment: @AnthonyKong I know this is old, but did you found a way to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue does not appear to be permission-related. The account running the command needs to be an authorized representative of the certificate domain. And the process for verifying that representative is specific to user accounts, not available for service accounts. So you would have to run `gcloud auth login` instead of `gcloud auth activate-service-account`.